# scroll to bottom using .animate scrollTop finishes before defined time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I'm using jQuery .animate to - on click scroll to the a section of the page. I have it in 3 times, 1 for scrolling back to the top (works fine), 1 for scrolling to section 2 (works fine) & 1 for scrolling to section 3.

When scrolling to section 3 (which is the bottom of the page) it seems to complete quicker than the defined time. So what ends up happening is that it scrolls straight to the bottom, but then its still running so you cant scroll up again till the time has elapsed.

The site its running on is new.pudle.co.uk (try clicking "get in touch" to see the problem in action)

the jQuery code i'm using is :

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {  


$('.proj-tile').click(function()   {
if($(window).scrollTop() >= 300) { //has scrolled considerably to animate
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '+0'   }, 1200);
}
});


$('#a-u').click(function()  {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '+800' }, 1200);
});


$('#c-u').click(function()  {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '+1500' }, 3000);
});

});
```

Comment: It seems to be behaving fine here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/DQQr4/1/

Comment: Why are you trying to load jQuery two times, `Google js Api loader` and `direct link` :s

Comment: @joy - good question, the jsapi is there becuase i need it to run -`google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {  $("#a-u, #c-u").click(function(){   $("#proj-content").load("projects/blank.html");   });   });` , but using the jsapi for  the rest of it dosnt seem to work for the rest of the scripts